# Modify attributes in 'Additional Params' for a Looker DB connection

Tags: liquid, looker

I'm trying to pass groups information to a mysql database using connection attributes with Looker.

Looker support passing additional parameters and use liquid format for inserting user attributes, eg
`connectionAttributes=looker.groups:{{_user_attributes['usergroup']}}`

which will result in a JDBC string as such:
`jdbc:mysql://host:port/mysql?connectionAttributes=looker.groups:ENGINEER,DEVELOPER`

connectionAttributes use comma as it's own delimiter so above will be parsed as two value pairs on database side:

```
looker.groups:ENGINEER
DEVELOPER:<nothing>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass both values (ENGINEER,DEVELOPER) under same key, changing delimiter to ; using liquid - but no success.

I've tried these

```
#in case usergroup is stored as string
{{_user_attributes['usergroup']  | replace: ",", ";"}}
#in case usergroup is stored as array
{{_user_attributes['usergroup']  | join: ";"}}
```

These are both not parsed by looker, but come back as-is
eg
`jdbc:mysql://host:port/mysql?connectionAttributes=looker.groups:{{_user_attributes['usergroup'] | replace: ",", ";"}}`

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was easy, the `userGroup` user attribute was user created (static), so changing that to use semicolon solve the problem statement above.
This raise another question, how to get the actual groups and not a static value - but I'll do my homework and spend some time to try figure that out.